# How to use Push Get Notification code in our app in android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Hi I m new in gcm services I really dont know how to use push get notification in our app. I read many article but no but i do not get good one if some one have code and processor of working please share with me . 
thank you.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?....I am also getting the same error.."Failed to register on attempt 1:java.net.ConnectException: /127.0.0.1:80 - Connection refused"..

Answer (score 3):

have you tried below link , it is useful for you to understand gcm

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: I am already  use this project . when i register it show the error could not register . in log cat it show register fail to the server

Comment: @Hardik- +1, This is a good example. Rishi- What error did you get in the app. you need to post what you have tried and what's the problem.!

Comment: thanks @SahilMahajanMj i think Rishi Gautam has not configured curl in php

Comment: @HardikNadiyapara   sir this my url  http://127.0.0.1/gcm_server_php/register.php  . When i also started the curl in php in logCat in showFailed to register on attempt 5:java.net.ConnectException: /127.0.0.1:80 - Connection refused

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj sir i jnw this is good example but  all ready mention the problem in above Failed to register on attempt 5:java.net.ConnectException: /127.0.0.1:80 - Connection refused

Comment: @HardikNadiyapara sir this is my id rishigautamg@gmail.com can you add me on email

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj
Log Tag dalvikvm
Log Message GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5901 objects / 357400 bytes in 366ms
log message(Error) Failed to register on attempt 5:java.net.ConnectException: /127.0.0.1:80 - Connection refused

Comment: sir @SahilMahajanMj can u add me on email account my id is rishigautamg@gmail.com

Comment: How should i add you on email account.! dont post your logcat in the comment. post it in the question by editing it.

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj sir i all ready post the log cat error is
Failed to register on attempt 5:java.net.ConnectException: /127.0.0.1:80 - Connection refused

Comment: Can you post the line where you got this error.? and please dont post in comments. edit your question and post there.

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj
 Failed to register on attempt 2:java.net.ConnectException: /127.0.0.1:80 - Connection refused

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19278/discussion-between-rishi-gautam-and-sahilmahajanmj)

Comment: The android hive tut is a good example of how to setup for GCM , but it doesnt really show us how to make our server push....thats what im having trouble understanding .